# Accessing profile info through user model Django

Tags: python, html, css, django

Hello I am a beginner with the django python framework.  I need to display a user's image and bio on a file named user_posts.html in my blog app.  I have it where I can access the user's image and bio by looping over the posts for the user.  However, I need it so it only displays the bio and the image once.  I have a separate profile.html in a users app.  In that file, I can do just src="{{ user.profile.image.url }}" and {{ user.profile.bio }} to access the users information but that does not seem to work in my user_posts.html because of the structure of my project.  I can't figure out how to tell the for loop to just go over once to access the users information.

users_post.html

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    
    <hr size="30">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column left">
        {% for post in posts %}
                <img style= "float:left" src="{{ post.author.profile.image.url}}" width="125" height="125">
                <h5 style="text-align: left;">{{ post.author.profile.bio }}</h5>
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
```

views.py

```
class UserPostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/user_posts.html' # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    paginate_by = 5
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        return Post.objects.filter(author=user).order_by('-date_posted')
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from PIL import Image

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
    bio = models.TextField(default='enter bio text here')
    

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

[This is what the problem looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85dZr.png)

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Two suggestions: (1) rewrite your view using View instead of ListView and just do what you actually want or (2) use `get_context_data()` (look it up in Django docs) to add in the User or Profile object to your context so you can access it separately from Posts. Give it a try and let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you might do it using `get_context_data()`.

```py
class UserPostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/user_posts.html' # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    paginate_by = 5
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        return Post.objects.filter(author=user).order_by('-date_posted')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        """
        Add User Profile to the template context.
        """
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        profile_user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        context['profile_user'] = profile_user
        return context
```

You'd then use `{{ profile_user.profile.bio }}` in your template instead of `posts` for the user profile info.

This is probably better than getting the first object in `posts` and getting the user profile information from that object in the case the user has no posts yet (but has a bio).

Note, we're fetching the `User` object both in `get_queryset` and in `get_context_data` so this is not super efficient. There are ways around this but I'll leave it to future editors or you to optimize :)

**Probably Not Recommended, But Answering Question**

Since you initially were just trying to get the first element, here's how I'd do it.

```
# Method 1
{% with first_post=posts|first %}
  {{ posts.user.profile.bio }}
  {{ posts.user.profile.image.url }}
{% endwith %}

# Method 2
{{ posts.0.profile.bio }}
{{ posts.0.profile.image.url }}
```

Comment: I tried to implement the code.   It seemed like it got some fields but I think there was an issue with formatting with the return context.  The error it gave was "Cannot resolve keyword 'username' into field. Choices are: bio, id, image, user, user_id".  How do you add the user profile to the template context?  I am confused on how to pass it through.  I changed username to bio and id but then it just said that the page couldnt be found

Comment: I figured out how to stop the loop though.  I added "{% for post in posts|slice:":1" %}" and that returns only the first element.  I do agree that your method is better and I should change my views so I can use the standard method of calling the model

Comment: Yeah sorry my initial answer is buggy because `Profile` doesn't have a `username` field, only `User` does. You can just change it to fetch `User` as you do in `get_queryset`. This is a bit inefficient since you're doing this twice, which is why I initially recommended maybe just writing a view "from scratch". But probably not a big deal performance wise. You should also look at `select_related()` as it will likely save you on # of queries when you have a foreign key or one-to-one field. Anyway, I'll edit the answer, hope it helps.

Comment: I finally figured it out using get_context_data.... thanks for the help!